# How to handle right click event on a grid item in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have used a list view that uses a grid view in WPF. I have bound the grid with data and I want to handle right click event on the items of the grid view. Can someone help me out and suggest how to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to provide what you need:

[wpf listview right-click problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075170/wpf-listview-right-click-problem)