# C# WinForms Right Click Context Menu without Selecting item

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I have a right click menu on c# winforms and the question is when I right click to get the menu how do I not get it to select the item when I right click?

I found a similar question, but it is for WPF [here at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075170/wpf-listview-right-click-problem)

The problem being that i have index_changed event that is affected by the right click and i don't want it to be.

Comment: I do not know of an index_changed event for the context menu.  What event are you using, Item_Clicked? Code is good too.

Comment: Please provide the event handler code.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want this to be handled in the Listviews selected index changed event.....  The sample below shows how to determine the button pressed.  Al it does is tell you yes or no if the right mouse button was clicked.  This is the simplest example I can show without knowing your code.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Form.MouseButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Right).ToString());
}
```

Comment: There are MouseDown and MouseUp event handlers. The MouseUp handler is the one that should be used to bypass selecting an index which would raise the handler you mention.

Comment: it fires off the index changed event before the mouse up event for the list view.

Comment: Try the MouseDown event - there is an event that fires to allow the OP to avoid changing the Index.