# ObservableCollection ListBox Item Remove Not Working

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a ListBox with binding, when i add Items it works perfect but if i try to remove the items with contextMenu it doesnt work.

Here is what i try so far **ListBox Xaml Code**

```
   <ListBox Name="lstPersons"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="126,-228,2,-242">
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="PersonContext">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Name="PersonDelete" Header="Delete" Click="DeletePerson_Click"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>    
                            <TextBlock Name="btnKellnerName"                                      
                                             Text="{Binding _PersonName}" 
                                             FontSize="35" 
                                             FontFamily="Portable User Interface"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="btnPosition"
                                             Text="{Binding _PersonPosition}"
                                             FontSize="22"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="lblUhrzeit" 
                                             Text="{Binding _CreationDate}"
                                             FontSize="18"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="Space" Text="                "/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

And the **Binding Class Code**

```
public class Person 
{    
    public string _PersonName { get; set; }      
    public string _PersonPosition { get; set; }    
    public string _CreationDate { get; set; }   
}
```

When i add items like this

```
ObservableCollection<Person> personList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

personList.Add(new Person { 
_PersonName = "Tom",
_PersonPosition = "Bla", 
_CreationDate = "33"
});

this.lstPerson.ItemSource = personList;
```

it works pefect! Now i Want to remove a selected Item with the ContextMenu like this

```
private void DeletePerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
   int indexPerson = lstPerson.SelectedIndex;

   personList.RemoveAt(indexPerson);
}
```

but it doesnt work. Does Anybody have an Idea what im making wrong? **Thanks**

Ok Guys i have now **the Solution** the Problem was the value of SelectedIndex now ive got the right Value. First ive put the ContextMenu inside ListBoxItemTemplate/StackPanel

Code Behind:

```
private void DeletePerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      try {

                var selectedListBoxItem = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(((MenuItem) sender).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
                var selectedIndex = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(selectedListBoxItem);

                _personList.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
         }
         catch( Exception ex ) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); };
  }
```

Comment: does it work if you add the item(s) before assigning `personList` to `ItemsSource`?  If not, there is a binding problem.  Also, is that a typo - should be `ItemsSource` not `ItemSource`.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Exception, or no exception and item remains in list?

Comment: Thanks guys for the Answers. I have debugged it and there Is a Problem wit listBox.SelectedIndex the value is -1. So the ContextMenu is not at the right place because i do not get the selected Index

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this when the form is initialized:

```
lstPersons.ItemsSource = personList ;
```

[How to: Create and Bind to an ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx)

It appears that the problem is due to selected item

> The key is setting the PreviewMouseRightButtonDown event in the
>   correct place. As you'll notice, even without a ContextMenu right
>   clicking on a ListViewItem will select that item, and so we need to
>   set the event on each item, not on the ListView.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
                         Handler="OnListViewItemPreviewMouseRightButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu Item">Item 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu Item">Item 2</MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListViewItem>Item</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Item</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Item</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Item</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Item</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Item</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

.

```
private void OnListViewItemPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Preview MouseRightButtonDown");

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

[wpf listview right-click problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075170/wpf-listview-right-click-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Ive tried it but i think the ContextMenu Delete event Code for deleting an Item doesnt Work.

Comment: Are you sure that the `lstPerson.SelectedIndex` has the right value?

Comment: The problem is the Value of SelectedIndex maybe the Context Menu isnt at the right place or i have the false event

Comment: Thanks buddy but i finally got the Problem fixed !

Comment: Great! :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Joan said, you can also do this in Xaml like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding personList}
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="126,-228,2,-242">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

</ListBox>
```

You should read how to use Bindings and the MVVM-Model. It's pretty convenient for stuff like this.
Here are some links:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/EX14
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03

Don't get discouraged. It's a bit of learning at the beginning, but it's totally worth it. I also had some problems with displaying lists, before I started doing everything with MVVM using Laurent Bugnions' MvvmLight package.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void DeletePerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
       System.Collections.IList pathRemove;
       pathRemove = lstPerson.SelectedItems;

       if(pathRemove.Count != 0)
          {
               for (int i = pathRemove.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        lstPerson.Remove((Person)pathRemove[i]);//multiple deletes
                    } 
         }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answers. I have debugged it and there Is a Problem wit listBox.SelectedIndex the value is -1. So the ContextMenu is not at the right place because i do not get the selected Index

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use binding for all.

Bind item source as ObservableCollection blabla

Bind Selecteditem as XXXX

Use command for your button and when you want remove an item do :

```
blabla.remove(SelectedItem);
```